# On setting background in a div using jQuery and JSON...

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I've been working on a way to get an species of database with only JSON and I managed to get it working [who knew that a "js/" in the url would make it work? :'(]

But that's not the problem, now I got an issue with CSS. Well, let's explain it.

I have this JSON:

```
[
    {
        "title":"Facebook",
        "url":"http://www.facebook.com",
        "bg":"../img/facebook.png"
    },
    {
        "title":"Twitter",
        "url":"http://twitter.com",
        "bg":"../img/twitter.png"
    }
]
```

This Markup:

```
<section id="links">
           <!-- here should be the <a>'s -->
</section>
```

And this JavaScript (using jQuery):

```
$(function(){
    $.getJSON('js/links.json', function(data){
        $.each(data, function(index){
            $("#links").append('<a href="'+data[index].url+'" style="background-image:url("'+data[index].bg+'");"><span>'+data[index].title+'</span></a>');
        });
    });
});
```

Now you say: It should work. And sure it works, but the background simply does not display. Seems that HTML goes nuts as I've seen in the [inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QchF.png).

Ok, then, what's wrong and what should I change?

Comment: mismatch in the quotes, remove the double ones in the `url()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem could be the way you have defined the style attribute.

```
style="background-image:url("'+data[index].bg+'");
```

The quotation mark directly after the opening parentheses is closing your style attribute. I would think simply removing it would do the trick

```
style="background-image:url('+data[index].bg+');
```

alternatively, replacing the double quote with an escaped single quote should also work

```
style="background-image:url(\''+data[index].bg+'\');
```

Comment: At first it didn't work, but I changed         `"bg":"../img/facebook.png"` to         `"bg":"img/facebook.png"` and it works, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your **"  "  "** with backslashes  **\**